# Image Upload from smartface io

Tags: smartface.io

Trying to upload image to my server can dev's help me plz with this. I am using this code to upload image 
    `var webClientUpload = new SMF.Net.WebClient({
        url : "http://services.smartface.io/Samples/File/Upload",
        httpMethod : "PUT", ploading
        onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) {
            Pages.startPage.cntUpload.lblSubtitleUpload.text = "Your file has"
            Pages.startPage.cntUpload.aiUpload.visible = false;
            Pages.startPage.cntUpload.imgUpload.visible = true;

```
    },
    onServerError : function (e) {
        Pages.startPage.cntUpload.lblSubtitleUpload.text = "There has been";
        Pages.startPage.cntUpload.aiUpload.visible = false;
        Pages.startPage.cntUpload.imgUpload.visible = true;
    }
});'
```

and I am changing the service to my service 
  http://devserver:922/UVService.svc 
Help me please anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know Smartface don't support file operations like upload, download or move.
Hope next releases solves the problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I have seen the code here [link] https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/file-download-upload/ so was confused @AlexGuba

Comment: if you try [link]https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/admob/ [/link] you will see that it also dont work.

Comment: @mervebıçakçı Please go through this errors in smartface app studio also in the next version I hope it will be solved.